# Http_authorization is null while working in .net4

Tags: html, asp.net, http-headers, iis-7.5

I wrote a website in aspx. The first version of it compiled on .Net 2, the application pool on the IIS -7.5 also was on .Net 2. The authentication In the IIS  was anonymous. This website returned the http_authorization,  here is the code that i wrote in the body section of the code:

`<body>
<%=request.servervariables["http_authorization"]%>
</body>`

It worked fine. When i surfed from the client to the website i saw the header of http_authorization.

But when I changed the code and the IIS on the server to .Net 4 version this header always returned `null`, although the server get this header (I checked it in wireshark).
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the properties of the application pool.
change the managed pipeline mode to **integrated**, and enable 32-bit applications to **true**.